# How to pass parameter in HTML video onplay

Tags: php, html, ajax

This is the code i am using for the on page videos. I have multiple videos on the page.

```
<video class='player' onplay='myFunction()' 
        data-id='$row[id]' oncontextmenu='return false;' 
        width='300' height='180' controls controlsList='nodownload'>
<source src='' type='video/mp4'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This is the javascript i am using to pass the parameters...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function myFunction(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { "videoId": $(this).data("id") },
        dataType:"Text",
    });
}
</script>
```

I am trying to insert the VIDEO ID in the database of the video when clicked to play.

For database i am using below code

```
if(isset($_POST['videoId'])){
    $videoId=$_POST['videoId'];
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO video 
                        (videoId,xx,yy) 
                    VALUES ('$videoId','$xx','$yy')") 
            or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even data from the database, [you are still at risk of corrupting your data](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: _"I am trying to insert the VIDEO ID in the database of the video when clicked to play."_ - and you probably could have succeeded already, if only you did event handling the proper jQuery way, instead of messing about with `onplay` attributes directly in the HTML code ... `$(this)` inside your handler function currently is not what you probably think it should be. Had you done this _properly_, using `$('.player').on('play', function(){ ...})`, `$(this)` would be referring to the correct element already.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.